# How to protect client script like a widget with OAuth?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, oauth

I created a widget that consist in a js script file that display specific information, the widget performs json calls to an specific server, I want to distribute the widget to an specific list of users. How can I protect my widget preventing it being used by other users that embeed the same client code? 
Is OAuth an effective way to protect it? How should I define the implementation of OAuth?

The implementation is using c# and asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure. OAuth is just another way of authentication of users. Can you please be more specific about that widget, if i understand well widget from client code is getting data from another specific servers that is not in your domain and your control. If I am wrong and that server is in your control that i am not sure what is the problem if you now which users can access specific data, than you can allow or prevent them in many ways.

Comment: Hi, this is practically the same scenario of google maps API, they provide an API Key to identify your requests and your API key was linked to your domain, they can block you or allow you. the only way to perform the validation is by checking the URL referrer.
My question objetive is to get a feedback about best practices to do this widget distribution, taking in account the security implications relateds... for example: I dont know the Referrer URL could be tampered?